# How to require Authentication and Encryption to access files and data streaming port on Ubuntu server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, authentication, encryption, streaming

I am new to Ubuntu/Linux, but I have been writing Python scripts to forward data from a usb/serial connection to multiple clients via tcp and telnet, while maintaining logs of the data locally on the server.

There is new data that may benefit from encryption and authentication.  I would like to encrypt the data from a serial connection, and stream it from a port, that multiple clients could connect to, and unencrypt the data with a username and password.  I am open to whatever may accomplish this the easiest.

Additionally I need to keep logs of the data.  If I can also encrypt the logs, I think that would be safer, however, as they are stored locally, it is less of a necessity.

Answer (score 0):

No sure if this is the best solution, but this is my idea so far using SSH...

On Server side:

```
Setup non-root user SSH account:
    https://serverfault.com/questions/555516/setup-public-key-authorized-ssh-for-non-root-users

Limit access to port 100 on server to only connections from localhost
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s localhost --dport 100 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 100 -j DROP

Setup encrypted folder for logging 
    https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FolderEncryption

Forward serial to TCP Stream on port 100, and log files to encrypted folder
    python streamer.......
```

On client side:

```
Remote Connect Via SSH Tunnel 
    ssh -L 30600:127.0.0.1:100 Non_Root_User@Server.com

Listin on 127.0.0.1:30600 for TCP stream
    telnet -o 127.0.0.1:30600
```